# Cramer's Rule with complex system of equations

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, systems-of-equations

Given a 2x2 system of complex equations with one unknown, $z$, written as a 2x2 matrix, $A$, would the system have infinitely many solutions iff $\det(A_x)=\det(A_y)=\det(A)=0$?  Or is there more to it than just finding the conditions under which the system is indeterminate?  I guess what I'm asking is it the same case as when dealing with real valued systems of equations?  Any help is appreciated along with some references if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an answer to a problem I had a while back, but it might be of use to other people who come across a similar question like this one.  But, after looking this up more thoroughly, I have concluded that Cramer's Rule works the same with real and complex numbers.  Here is the [reference](http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bradd/courses/math1b3/Chap10.pdf).

**Example.** We can use Cramer's rule to solve this system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}ix+2y=1-2i\\4x-iy=-1+3i\end{cases}$$
Using Cramer's Rule we get
$$x=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}1-2i&2\\-1+3i&-i\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}i&2\\4&-i\end{vmatrix}}=\frac{-i(1-2i)-2(-1+3i)}{i(-i)-2(4)}=\frac{-7i}{-7}=i\\y=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}i&1-2i\\4&-1+3i\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}i&2\\4&-i\end{vmatrix}}=\frac{i(-1+3i)+4(1-2i)}{i(-i)-2(4)}=\frac{-7+7i}{-7}=i-1$$
Therefore, the solution is $x=i,\ y=i-1.$

Comment: I think the the value of y = 1 - i